# Slim framework .htaccess 403 Forbidden

Tags: .htaccess, slim

I used to work on localhost with this .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

now when I uploaded it online it's giving me 403 Forbidden, is there any other things to change in that file.

Comment: Your file seems all right, its like the one in the [samples](https://github.com/slimphp/Slim/blob/88bc70973d6dde7620f1287b4d7681923e0e616a/example/.htaccess) of Slim. Probably the problem is on the server config or in the index.php location.

Comment: IIRC its a problem with AllowOverride in your apache config